# How to get "this" on click element in OOP JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

I have the following bit of JS:

```
bindEvents: function() {
  this.extra.bind("click", {context: this}, this.checkPackage.bind(this));
},
checkPackage: function(e) {
  console.log(e.data.context);
}
```

What I want is the `checkPackage` method to be like `$(this).whatever`, but I can't seem to access the clicked object. It just selects a the first object from the DOM with the `this.extra` class. How could I make this work?

Comment: That doesn't look like jquery to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `e.currentTarget` for the object, where the eventlistener is attached to. `e.target` will give u the actual clicked object (could be different).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `e.target` to get the clicked element.

```
bindEvents: function() {
  this.extra.bind("click", {context: this}, this.checkPackage.bind(this));
},
checkPackage: function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer  [jQuery event docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/), but summary as follows:

> **event.currentTarget**
>
> The current DOM element within the event bubbling phase.
>
> **event.delegateTarget**
>
> The element where the currently-called jQuery event handler was
>   attached.
>
> **event.relatedTarget**
>
> The other DOM element involved in the event, if any.
>
> **event.target**
>
> The DOM element that initiated the event.

In your case .you can use below code

```
bindEvents: function() {
  this.extra.bind("click", {context: this}, this.checkPackage.bind(this));
},
checkPackage: function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
}
```